# Unable to register for Push Notifications (Xcode 7, iOS9)

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios9, xcode7

I've upgraded my devices to iOS 9 and my Xcode environment to 7.0 (7A220).  My app registers for notifications via:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

However, neither "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationWithDeviceToken" or "didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError" are called.  Furthermore, my app does not appear in the Settings->Notifications section (which tells me its not even trying to register for remote/push notifications)

My App ID has the following Application Services enabled:

- Game Center
- In-App Purchase
- Push Notifications

In Xcode, the following capabilities enabled:

- Push Notifications
- Background Modes (Remote Notifications)

This worked fine with iOS 8, with app built with Xcode 6. Also, it no longer works with an iOS 8 device when built with Xcode 7.

Answer (score 14):

Do you use a simulator?

In a simulator, remote notifications are not supported.

sample code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let pushSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [UIUserNotificationType.Badge ,UIUserNotificationType.Sound ,UIUserNotificationType.Alert], categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(pushSettings)
    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let token=deviceToken.description
    print(token)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    print(error)
}
```

Xcode says:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
Code=3010 "REMOTE_NOTIFICATION_SIMULATOR_NOT_SUPPORTED_NSERROR_DESCRIPTION"
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=REMOTE_NOTIFICATION_SIMULATOR_NOT_SUPPORTED_NSERROR_DESCRIPTION}
```

Answer (score 8):

The reason why it wasn't working was because I wasn't calling:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
```

Prior to the call:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Comment: How did you had achieved..? I did the same but push notifications are not coming. It do registers for notification but it is not going in didRecieveRemoteNotification

Comment: Why on earth is this not documented in Apple's documentaion ?