# iOS app upgraded from iOS8 SDK to 9, doesn't receive notifications

Tags: swift2, apple-push-notifications, ios9

I recently updated an app from iOS8 (swift 1.2) to iOS9, swift 2.2 on Xcode 7.3.

The app works fine, except that **notifications are no longer received**.

If I use Xcode 6.3 to build my iOS8 branch (master), the app when deployed to my phone receives notifications just fine.

If I use Xcode 7.3 to build my iOS9 branch, the app does not receive notifications.

I've gone over the usual suspects. I'm not getting any errors when registering for notifications, and my code signing and provisioning profiles all seem to be in order.

My registration is standard boilerplate:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
let userNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert, categories: nil)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(userNotificationSettings)
```

Is there some difference in notification registration on iOS9? I can't seem to find any differences when googling, but I'm open to any pointers.

Thanks,

**SO: THE PLOT THICKENS**

For sanity checking, I switched back to my master branch, which uses swift 1.2 and iOS8 SDK, and built and redeployed to an older iPhone running iOS8. And, horrifyingly, notifications **are not being received anymore**

Meanwhile, if I re-install the last TestFlight build I made, using the same codebase, notifications work.

I'm beginning to wonder if there's some issue here from my having Xcode 6.3 and Xcode 7.3 running on the same machine, maybe mucking up some aspect of code-signing? Is that plausible?

Comment: Are you getting back confirmation that you're registered for alerts in `func application(application: UIApplication!, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings!) { 
}`?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if you need to add the 'Push Notifications' app service for the project or not (it's been a while since I did this in Xcode).

Comment: Yes on the delegate method (it reports the setting I requested). The "Push Notifications" entitlement is set too.

Comment: Change your calls around.  Call `registerForRemoteNotifications()` after `registerUserNotificationSettings`.  Per this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32706042/3487310

Are you doing this on the simulator or a real device?  I've read that notifications don't work in the simulator.

Comment: I just swapped the calls, per your suggestion. I also tried deferring the call to registerForRemoteNotifications in the delegate callback for registerUserNotificationSettings. No dice. And, yeah, I'm running on real hardware - the simulator does not support notification. I am at a loss here! I must be doing something wrong with the app signing, because the only other times I've seen notifications quietly ignored like this is is because of a signing issue.